# groovy dynamic script execution woes: neither GroovyShell, nor GroovyClassLoader want to work in context of passed-in class loader

Tags: java, groovy

i'm trying to get a dynamically generated groovy script to inherit classes and implement interfaces from the calling java program.  I'm passing in the class loader of the class that evaluates the groovy script to no avail.  I'm wondering if I could ask one of the Groovy experts out there what i might be doing wrong ?

The code is shown below.  in both cases the class "X" that is defined in the context of the calling code is not recognized when the script is evaluated.  I get messages like
" Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class X"

```
import org.junit.Test

import java.lang.reflect.Method

public class GroovyPuzzler {

    public static class X {
    String hello = "said-hello"
    }


    @Test
    public void test1() {
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Object script = shell.evaluate(
        """
def sayHello() {
        println new X().hello;

}
return  this
""");
    Method m = script.getClass().getMethod("sayHello");
    m.invoke(script);

    }



    @Test
    public void test2() {
    String script =
        """
public class Boo {
    def sayHello() {
        println new X().hello;

     }

}
"""
    ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
    GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
    Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(script);

    GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
    Object[] args = {};
    groovyObject.invokeMethod("sayHello", args);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea how to catch output (`SystemOutputInterceptor` ???) from script invoked in such a way so I changed `println` to `throw` to illustrate that it really works.

What You need to do is to `import` the class You'd like to use. Here goes the code:

```
package sample

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ImportCustomizer
import org.junit.Test

import java.lang.reflect.Method

public class GroovyPuzzler {

    public static class X {
        def hello2() {
            throw new RuntimeException("bang!")
        }
    }

    @Test 
    public void test1() {
        def customizer = new ImportCustomizer()
        customizer.addImport('X', 'sample.GroovyPuzzler.X')
        def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
        configuration.addCompilationCustomizers(customizer)

        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(configuration)
        Object script = shell.evaluate(
        """
            def sayHello() {
                new X().hello2()
            }
            return this
        """
        )
        try {
           Method m = script.getClass().getMethod("sayHello")
           m.invoke(script)
           fail()
        } catch (Exception e) {
           assertTrue(e.cause.message.equals('bang!'))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: import the class !   yes !   what dummy i am.   hey, thanks ;^)